# TFS stand-alone MS Excel/Project add-ons

Tags: ms-office, add-on

I want to know if there is a stand-alone setup for TFS Excel/Project add-ons or not. I know I can obtain them through Team Explorer but the problem with it are :

1- It is a huge (+300Mb) setup file
2- It is a complicated process setup for people who have no any knowledge of VS and TFS. Always a developer should be there for installation

I will be so excited if there is a light stand-alone installer for TFS Excel/Project add-ons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't, but you can create an answer file for Team Explorer to install it silently with just one click.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225237.aspx

You can place this install on a network share.

I'm not sure if you can register a new server connection from a script. I've asked the powers that be.

The powers that be have responded, you can export your own TFS server registrations (or create a .reg file from scratch) and import those on the new machine in order to pre-populate the connection window:

[Martin Woodward ‏ @martinwoodward:

@jessehouwing](https://twitter.com/#!/martinwoodward/status/179689359476396032) See `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamFoundation\Instances` (or 10.0 for VS2010)

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it is complicated a little.

Comment: It's never easy, but once you've created the unattended setup, then it's very easy :).

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot but didn't solve my problem. The problem should be solved by Microsoft :)

Comment: But that won't change this answer one bit. This is the solution you have right now. There is no alternative and TFS11 hasn't improved it. If you want the behavior changed, file a bug on http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio or on uservoice http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Answer (score -2):

When “Team” add-in goes missing from Office:
•Go to Excel Options
•Select COM add-ins and add “TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll”  from “C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
 Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies”
•In case if its not there install Team Explorer 2010